# API YOUTUBE Data users

Tags: api, youtube

I'm trying to categorize people. 
For this reason, I consider (it is a postulate...) that YOUTUBE subscriptions represent the person quite well. 
I wanted to know if it was possible, with the user's agreement, to retrieve his subscriptions from the Youtube API. Any leads?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. send a query with these parameters to the API, and you will get the response.

```
return gapi.client.youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({ 
    "ids": "channel==channelID", 
    "metrics": "subscribersGained", 
    "dimensions": "day", 
    "sort": "day" 
});
```

you can also add:

```
"startDate": "2010-03-01", 
"endDate": "2010-03-02"
```

More info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/javascript